# Where can I find all tables used in ManagementObjectSearcher in win32 API

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I was getting curious to know various classes/tables that can be queried for ManagementObject to read hardware details.

e.g.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher adapters = 
new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
```

i.e.

```
1. Win32_NetworkAdapter
2. Win32_LogicalDisk
3. Win32_Service
```

Where can I find whole list of such tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could select appropriate tables from the following list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx

You could also get this list programmatically:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher wmi = new ManagementObjectSearcher
    ("SELECT * FROM meta_class WHERE __CLASS LIKE 'Win32_%'");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in wmi.Get())
    Console.WriteLine(obj["__CLASS"]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft's [*WMI Code Creator*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) is handy for this, its a utility that lists all WMI classes in a searchable fashion, it will generate VBScript code you can run immediately to see whats actually returned and you can then use it to spit out C#/VB.Net code snippets.

[image]